# Arrays shown in output after user input

Tags: java, arrays, string, project

I can't seem to have my array to appear in the output here is my coding. Is there a problem?
I want my 'Jan' array to appear in my menu for example: "Jan Expenditure" however only "expenditure is appearing. And now i have a syntax error on String monthChoice. Please help me out. Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Project {
static String[] itemList = new String[10];
static int[] amountList = new int[10];
static int choice;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    {   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("***************Expenditure***************");
        System.out.println("1)Enter monthly expenses");
        System.out.println("2)Display detailed expenditure by month");
        System.out.println("3)Quick glance at monthly expenses");
        System.out.println("4)Exit");
        System.out.println("Please select your choice <1-3>:");
        choice = input.nextInt();


        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            int count = 0;
            String[] monthsArray = { "", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
                    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
            System.out.println("*******************************************");
            System.out.println("\t\t\t\t");
            System.out.print("Enter month <1 for Jan - 12 for Dec>:");
            int month = input.nextInt();
            for (int i=0; i < monthsArray.length; i++)
            String monthChoice = monthsArray[month - 1];
            System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(monthChoice + "expenditure (max 10 items)");
```

Comment: If month = 1 , monthsArray[0] = "" so it's normal.

Comment: why do you have a for in the middle of the function doing nothing
why do you put a empty string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
String monthChoice = monthsArray[month - 1];
```

Should be:

```
String monthChoice = monthsArray[month];
```

Because the first month is empty.

Also, I don't understand this `for` loop, since you don't even use the `i` variable, and you don't need to repeat that action multiple times:

```
for (int i=0; i < monthsArray.length; i++)
```

Comment: +1 especially for the for ;)

Comment: i understand my mistakes now thanks for the help. i just started learning programming so i think i still have a lot to learn. thanks for the help. I can finally move on to do the other programming for my project

Comment: These errors are common in the early days :) Please, mark answer as accepted. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: A user enters the number 1 and you assign it to your `month` variable so now `month = 1`. The first line in your for loop now asks for `monthsArray[month - 1]` which is `monthsArray[1-1]` which turns into `monthsArray[0]`. The 0<sup>th</sup> element of your `monthsArray` is an empty string "". When you print this as monthChoice you get only the 2<sup>nd</sup> part of your string so it looks like you are getting a result you don't want.